# Iterate through Json data

Tags: javascript, json

So I have this array of JSON objects:

```
[
  {
    "columns": [
      {
        "fields": [
          {
            "valueFields": [
              {
                "type": 1,
                "fieldName": "prj_Name",
                "value": "1A BNL FB e-Powedr basic Balci Reizen",
                "valueId": "",
                "defaultValue": false,
                "baseValue": false,
                "mandatoryField": true,
                "hasError": false,
                "errorMessage": "",
                "disabled": false,
                "visible": true
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

and I would like to Iterate through the Data to do some stuff with it later.

I already tried this :

```
for (var key in currentObject) {
    if (currentObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(key + ': ' + currentObject[key]);
    }
}
```

But it prints every letter separatly in the console, so I guess it isn't right.
Do you have any Ideas of what I am doing wrong ?

[EDIT]

I tried to add `var currentObject = JSON.parse(Json);` before the `for` loop.

I now get this printed `0: [object Object]`

How to iterate through the object then ?

Comment: `JSON.parse(currentObject)` because it's really a string...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JsonObject is a JsonArray in a JsonArray in a JsonArray in a JsonArray...

Try the following code [online](https://jsfiddle.net/k38bckLk/1/), it works for your case

```
var x  = '[{"columns":[{"fields":[{"valueFields":[{"type":1,"fieldName":"prj_Name","value":"1A BNL FB e-Powedr basic BalciReizen","valueId":"","defaultValue":false,"baseValue":false,"mandatoryField":true,"hasError":false,"errorMessage":"","disabled":false,"visible":true}]}]}]}]';
var parsedJson = JSON.parse(x);
var valueFields = parsedJson[0].columns[0].fields[0].valueFields[0];

for (var key in valueFields) {
    if (valueFields.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(key + ': ' + valueFields[key]);
    }
}
```

I would suggest to change the output if it's only one result to make it easier to parse. If you have access to modify the server code ofcourse.

Comment: This is the simpliest reauest I had to show you. In some cases It could happen that I get multiple columns with multiple fields having multiple valuefields in it.

Comment: So I guess I should add `foreach` loop to iterate through each Array of the Object. Thx a lot for your help.

Comment: You have to make multiple loops if you want to handle your main json, `columns`, `fields` and `valueFields`.